# How to find UIViewController is in active or inactive iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, badge

I am working in tabBar based iPhone app.

- I have 5 UIViewControllers in tabbar controller.
- In my application I have used APNS. When APNS received I want to update data in `UIViewController` 4.
- If the user working in `UIViewController`s 1,2,3 and 5 i want to update the data in `UIViewController` 4 and show badges.
- I refresh and updated the data in UIViewController 4 but I want to show the badge if the user not in the `UIViewController` 4.
- If the user currently in `UIViewController` 4 i don't want to show the badges.

How can i find another one `UIViewController` is in active or inactive from some other `UIViewController`?

**Edit**

I have tried below code to get the selectedIndex of UITabBarController.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%d", appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex);
```

Comment: Can't you just get it with the 'selectedViewController' property of your tab bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with a `UITabBarController` you can easily ask for the currently selected tab which should result in the active view controller. Try the methods:
[selectedViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController) or
[selectedIndex](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedIndex)

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I have tried to get the selectedIndex but the value of selectedIndex not updating. It returning previous selected tab index. Could you please advice me? Thanks.